# MSDN documentation error? ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript does not execute for every asynchronous postback

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0, msdn, scriptmanager

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method, `(Page, Type, String, String, Boolean)` overload, registers a script for "**every** asynchronous postback with the ScriptManager control and adds the script block to the page." Yet, that does not seem to be the behavior. Instead, the script executes **only once**, on the next page or UpdatePanel render following the call of the method. It does not even need to be within an asynchronous postback: a regular postback, or initial GET will also cause the script to execute.

This must be an error in the documentation. What do you think? Run the sample below, and note that after registering the startup script, the alert is displayed, but then when clicking the other dummy button to cause another postback, the alert is not displayed, because the script is not executed. And yet, you can click the register button again, and the alert will again be displayed, showing that the behavior is not caused by some sort of suppression of duplicate script keys.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunction() { alert("MyFunction"); }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRegisterStartupScript" text="RegisterStartupScript" OnClick="btnRegisterStartupScript_Click" runat="server"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnDummyPostback" Text="Dummy Postback" runat="server" />
            <%=DateTime.Now%>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">
    protected void btnRegisterStartupScript_Click(object oSender, EventArgs e) {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "MyFunction", "MyFunction();", addScriptTags: true);
    }
</script>
```

Personally, I don't mind this behavior, as there needs to be a method that allows developers to run a script only on the current async postback. But I think the documentation should be more accurate. The documented behavior can be achieved, but only if you call `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "MyFunction", "Sys.Application.add_load(function() { MyFunction(); });", addScriptTags: true);` which will use the client-side framework to register the script within the anonymous function block.

Comment: `Registers a startup script block for every asynchronous postback with the ScriptManager control and adds the script block to the page.` Alert message is displayed every time RegisterStartupScript button is clicked. ***It works exactly what is stated. What do you expect to happen?***

Comment: @Win: If it was working as stated, I would see the alert *for every asynchronous postback*. Instead, I don't see the alert when I trigger an asynchronous postback via the dummy button.

Comment: Asynchronous postback via dummy button did not register `MyFunction` to ScriptManager; it is why `MyFunction` is not called again. **Please keep in mind that `every asynchronous postback` is unique due to ASP.Net's stateless nature.** In other words, it doesn't maintain the previous postback's values.

Comment: @Win: I don't understand how your comment is relevant. Try the example again, and note that after registering the startup script block, you can click the dummy postback button to trigger another asynchronous postback, and the script will not be executed. So it comes down to this question: What is the meaning of the words "for every asynchronous postback" in the documentation? Why even include those words, if the behavior is to only include the script for the first subsequent postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation for the other overload of this method, [RegisterStartupScript(Control, Type, String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I think I have the answer: The words "for every asynchronous postback" are intended as a *contrast* to the behavior of this overload:

> Startup script blocks that are registered by using this method are
>   sent to the page only when the control that is registering the block
>   is inside an UpdatePanel control that is being updated.

In other words, the first overload registers the startup script only when the specified control is within an UpdatePanel being updated, whereas the second overload registers the startup script regardless, *every time it called*. Somehow this gave birth to the phrasing "for every asynchronous postback", which is not accurate. A better way to phrase it would be "Registers a startup script block with the ScriptManager control and adds the script block to the page. The script block is executed only once, when the page or UpdatePanel is rendered."

I have submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809648/msdn-documentation-error-scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-does-not-execute-for-every-asynchronous-postback) to Connect, and I will mark this answer accepted if they agree with me.

Comment: The first-tier screener at Connect doesn't quite understand the problem with the docs, but they haven't closed the bug, so there is still hope to get the documentation changed :)